# How to rearrange different type of associative array in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to rearrange to different type of associative array to extract same property.
So I tried to make sample code below.

```
const array1 = [{name:'john',age:25},{name:'Bob',age:33}];
const array2 = [{name:'Jen',age:35,id:1},{name:'Mera',age:31,id:2}];
const array3 = array1.concat(array2);
console.log(array3)
```

and this code reuld is like that.

```
0: {name: "john", age: 25}
1: {name: "Bob", age: 33}
2: {name: "Jen", age: 35,id:1}
3: {name: "Mera", age: 31,id:2}
```

my goal is just below.

```
0: {name: "john"}
1: {name: "Bob"}
2: {name: "Jen"}
3: {name: "Mera"}
```

Could someone adivise me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the values to have a `name` property, then you should just [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the array elements to ones with just a `name` property.  For example:

```
const array3 = [...array1, ...array2].map(({ name }) => ({ name }));

console.log(array3); 
// [ { "name": "john" }, { "name": "Bob" }, { "name": "Jen" }, { "name": "Mera" } ]
```

Here I'm using [spread in array literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_array_literals) instead of `concat()`, and [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) for the object mapping.  If those are weird looking, you could rewrite it as:

```
const array4 = array1.concat(array2).map(value => ({ name: value.name }));
```

which does pretty much the same thing.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.0.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwXAngRhgXhgbQN4xhwC2ApgFwwDkAViABZhUA08A5hTAEwCsMAvqwJEylKgCEQAIxbtOAZnkCAugG4AUKEixEyFFyy5hJTlQBSpJqzgdK8nqwCWAE0oZBMY6OoBZUslkbBTQnV24VDS1oeCRUJWwcADpk3VQQmGTE1P1lROI4AAcACiKvUgEASiwAPhhSwhNKisjwCBAAG1JE9pA2Iuz5ZpgAemGYXE8YACIRUinKKbpGKYEhadn56ckpFY8CGZNNqYswXbWDsiO-ZF2YZRh1TVadWJQAFkNstEStYDgofqvLgVPKFIoANzg7QAruVMLV6rNKJCYV1Zk0WpAOl0en1sm8hkA)

Comment: You don't need that `.slice()`?